# Can I put my app to first in share menu programmatically?

Tags: ios, share, ios-app-extension, share-extension

As the title.
Can I put my app to first in share menu programmatically?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elCUD.png)

Comment: Not programaticaaly

Comment: No, you can't do it

Comment: Let's pretend for a moment that this is possible. Then what happens when every app installed on a device wants to be first?

Comment: The order of the items in the share menu is controlled by the user. As it should be.

Comment: Thank you, you are my hero.
Also, can I enable my app in Activities screen programaticaly?